# Meteor mongoDB query on a selector but unique results based on another

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Is there any way to query on a field but make sure the result is unique based on another field ?

ex:

```
Available.find({available: "2016-02-06"}, {sort: {userId: 1}};
```

Now I want to make sure there are no duplicate userId's in result. I could'nt find anything built in, what is the best way to achieve this ?

*I know I can use _.uniq but not sure if this is efficient on a larger selection?

Comment: do you want to know `userId` duplicate or not in `available` date ?

Comment: @shaishabroy I want all tuples that match an array of available entries/dates but are also unique in userId. because a userId can be part of multiple date entries

Comment: you can use `distinct` like  `db.collection.distinct(field, query)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Available.distinct("available");
```